# Reading from IRandomAccessStreamReference

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-10, windows-mobile

I'm working with the windows 10 ***Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat*** API. I can't seem to figure out how to read the data from the **DataStreamReference** property in the **ChatMessageAttachment** object. Here's my code so far.

As you can see, it throws an exception with the message "Specified cast is not valid." The **IBuffer** interface makes no sense since all is has is the **Length** and **Capacity** property.

I'll appreciate if someone can give me some tips on how to read from that **DataStreamReference** property.

```
var store = await ChatMessageManager.RequestStoreAsync();
var conversations = await store.GetConversationReader().ReadBatchAsync();

foreach (var conversation in conversations)
{
    var messages = (await conversation.GetMessageReader().ReadBatchAsync(int.MaxValue)).ToArray();
    foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        try
        {
            var dataStream = await message.Attachments.First().DataStreamReference;
            var stream = await dataStream.OpenReadAsync();

            var buffer = new Ass(); // Implements IBuffer
            var count = (uint)stream.Size;

            // Throws exception - "Specified cast is not valid."
            await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, count, Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.ReadAhead);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    using (var datastream = (await dataStream.OpenReadAsync()).AsStreamForRead())
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(datastream);
    string result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

Comment: thank you. This is what I'm looking for. Didn't know those extension methods existed.